# Python connect to MySQL database on web server

Tags: python, database, web, connection, server

I wanted to know the process of connecting to a MySQL database that is hosted on a web server.

I have a basic free webserver for testing on 000webhost on which I created a MySQL database.

I have the credentials for the database which I will pretend are
host     - mysql.webhost000.com
user     - dummy_user
password - dummy_password
database - dummy_database

and I have a python script executing from my local computer with internet access

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql.webhost000.com",
                     port=3306,
                     user="dummy_user",
                     passwd="dummy_password",
                     db="dummy_database")
```

I was hoping it would connect as long as I have the right credentials but when I execute the script it just hangs and once I quit it I see the error

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.webhost000.com' (4)
```

Am I missing some steps?

Comment: There is a quotation mark missing in your code.

Comment: that was just a typo when making this post, fixed it though

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems and im not able to recreate the first one.  One is the

```
host="mysql.webhost000.com"
```

is incorrect and throwing an error.  The connection could be listed as another way.  The other I noticed is this is usually how I set up my connection script.

import MySQLdb

```
def connect():
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="mysql.webhost000.com",
                     port=3306,
                     user="dummy_user",
                     passwd="dummy_password",
                     db="dummy_database")

    c = conn.cursor()

    return c, db
```